# Netty eclipse "no mandatory external dependencies"? import errors

Tags: eclipse, netty

I just downloaded Netty for a personal client-server-project from here:
http://netty.io/downloads/netty-3.3.0.Final-dist.tar.bz2
On the download page http://netty.io/downloads/ it says there are "no mandatory external dependencies". You only need a JDK 1.5 or higher. So I just set up a java project in eclipse IDE using my 1.6 JDK and got multiple errors saying "import cannot be resolved".

Examples:
`org.jboss.logging`, `com.google`, `org.osgi`, `javax.servlet`

That tells me that there are actually some external libraries needed. Or am I doing anything wrong?

Can anyone tell me where to find all these libraries since I could not find any clues on the Netty pages where to get them (I know that javax.servlet is part of Tomcat and JBoss AS distribution, but why do they then say that no external libraries are needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to build netty from source? There's a `pom.xml` file in the root, implying that netty can be built by maven. You'll find all those dependencies in the pom file. "No mandatory external dependencies" means that you need no jar other than the netty jar to run your application. External dependecies is probably needed for some of the examples, definitively for testing and perhaps for some special, but optional, run time features.

Comment: Yeah, well, thanks. Sorry that I did not comment over the weekend. I am actually writing my own server for a personal game project and wanted to have a look at netty source to get a better understanding of how SocketChannels and all this stuff works. I am currently thinking that just using Netty and learning how it works is maybe the better approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies are only used for building and are marked as optional. The dependencies are only needed if you want for example use slf4j for logging in netty. Beside this netty can be used within your project without pulling in any third-party dependencies.